# Dynamic user interfaces in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a button, and a layout, which loads a custom `QWidget`. I want to change the widget in the layout into another sample widget when clicking a button. The previous widget should be completely replaced by the new widget. How could I achieve such an effect?

Source Code:
http://paste.opensuse.org/51831462

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. Also mention if you're using any specific derived of `QLayout`?

Answer (score 2):

[QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstackedwidget.html) is perfect for what you want to achieve.

You will have to redesign a bit your code, but the result will be simpler to understand and to maintain. You just have to change the current widget of the QStackedWidget when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with setCentralWidget().
Could you include your source code in your question?

Comment: Try
l->removeWidget(m);
l->addWidget(label);

Comment: removeWidget(button) and then addWidget(label) adds the label, but does not remove the label. the label is added over the button

Comment: Try adding setFocus(); after l->addWidget(label);

Comment: even after using setFocus, I can still see the button, though I cant click on it

Comment: What happens when you explicitely hide the button with button->hide();?

Comment: Okay, I gues the problem is the QHBoxLayout takes care of adding the button at the right position and showing it. When you remove the button from the layout it only removes the reference. It does not take care of hiding it. That is why you have to do it explicitely.

Comment: explicitly calling delete on the button also works, and i think is much more efficient